# Responding to click event on <canvas> (Moving object)

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript (2 weeks) so I apologise of this is a really obvious question:

I have managed to get 2 red 'balls' to bounce around a canvas. I would now like to attach some sort of onclick event to them so that if one is clicked it changes colour, hopefully all pretty simple stuff..

I tried to add an onlick event like this -

```
p.onclick="gogreen(this, 'green')";**
```

Which triggers a function -

```
function gogreen(elmnt,clr)
{
elmnt.style.color = clr;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  "OK you clicked a ball";
}
```

But this doesn't work. No errors or anything but nothing actually happens when the objects are clicked.

I have also tried to add a listener but that wasn't successful either. Any advice you can give me would be appreciated as I have been banging my head against this for a few hours now.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Changing Red to Green</title>

<style type="text/css">
</style>

</head>

<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<div id="main_div">

<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">

</canvas>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Initialise the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

///Put the canvas dimesnions into variables for later use
var W = 500; 
var H = 500;

//Create an array so that we can pop out particles
var particles = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
//This will add a particle to the array
particles.push(new create_particle());

}


//This creates a unique(ish) particle each time its called
function create_particle()
{

//Random position on the canvas
this.x = Math.random()*W;
this.y = Math.random()*H;

    //this is the code to stop the ball getting 'stuck' at the edges, which         happens a lot

    if (this.x < 35) {
    this.x = this.x+35
    }

    if (this.x > W - 50) {
    this.x = this.x-35
    }

    if (this.y < 35) {
    this.y = this.y+35
    }

    if (this.y > H - 50) {
    this.y = this.y-35
    }   


//Add random velocity to each particle
this.vx = Math.random()*20-10;
this.vy = Math.random()*20-10;

//Random size
this.radius = Math.random()*20+20;

}


//change the color to green and change some text on the page
function gogreen(elmnt,clr)
{
elmnt.style.color = clr;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  "OK you clicked a ball";

}


// this draws the particles 
function draw()
{

//Paint the canvas black each draw
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";

//Draw the particles from the array now
for(var t = 0; t < particles.length; t++)
{
    var p = particles[t];

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fill();

    //Apply the movement
    p.x += p.vx;
    p.y += p.vy;

    //Add onclick event here
    p.onclick="gogreen(this, 'red')";


    //Bounce if the ball hits the edges
    if(p.x < p.radius) p.vx *= -1;
    if(p.y < p.radius) p.vy *= -1;
    if(p.x > W-p.radius) p.vx *= -1;
    if(p.y > H-p.radius) p.vy *= -1;

 }
}

//Starts the draw and sets the refresh rate
setInterval(draw, 33);

</script>
```

Comment: Well for starters, the `create_particle` object is not a DOM element nor does it have an `onclick` function. Even if it did, it would need to be a function, not a string. And even then, a canvas is just pixels rendered on a screen. You need to attach your `click` event to the canvas, then check if the mouse coordinates are within the area of the particle.

Comment: OK trickier than I had hoped for. I can apply the click event to the canvas I think but the objects are moving and I was going to add more of them. Would I put the latest particle co-ordinates into an array?  If I could do this I'm not sure sure how I could search for them in the array. Possibly I have gone about this the wrong way to start with?

Comment: I believe you have an array of particles? Loop through that and check the coordinates of each until you find one.

Comment: The array only holds the starting positions of the particles so i don't think that's an option for me. Thanks for the input BTW

Comment: No it doesn't - it holds the particles and you are updating their `x` and `y` properties ;)

Comment: [Here you go](https://jsfiddle.net/3zuukL01/), have a look at how I've done it. The basic idea is what I've already given you: use a click handler on the canvas and check with the coordinates of the particles.

Comment: That is perfect! I am now going to spend the rest of the evening trying to figure out the maths you used for the distance variable :) Many Thanks

Comment: It's fairly basic distance calculation using Pythagoras' theorem. X difference and Y difference are your side lengths, so square them, add them together, take square root and you have the distance in the hypotenuse.